# How to produce time delays in PIC18 ASM programming?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, assembly

I'm a newbie with microcontrollers programming. I have a high level programming understanding but I'm getting involved in low lever CPU/Microcontrollers development.

I want to do this simple exercise of getting an array of LED's on and off for 1 second each.

I tried this assembly (thinking about two leds):

```
    List    P=18F4550           
    include <P18F4550.inc>          



    CONFIG FOSC = INTOSC_EC ;INTOSC_EC          ; Internal oscillator                                
    CONFIG PWRT= ON             ; Power-up Timer Enable bit
    CONFIG BOR=OFF              ; Brown-out Reset disabled in hardware and software
    CONFIG WDT=OFF              ; WDT disabled
    CONFIG MCLRE=ON             ; MCLR pin enabled
    CONFIG PBADEN=OFF           ; PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O
    CONFIG LVP=OFF              ; Single-Supply ICSP disabled
    CONFIG DEBUG = OFF                  ; Background debugger disabled
    CONFIG XINST = OFF          ; Extended Instruction disabled
;******************************Variables***********************************
    count equ 0x00

;**********************************************************************************


    org     0x0000  
    movlw   0x62       
    movwf   OSCCON     ;Working at 4 MhZ
    clrf    TRISD      ;D port as output
    ;leds OFF so far

LGHTLOOP
    bcf PORTD,0         
    call DELAY

    bsf PORTD,0         
    CALL DELAY

    bcf PORTD,1         
    call DELAY

    bsf PORTD,1       
    CALL DELAY

bra  LIGHTLOOP

DELAY
    movlw   .1000  
    movwf   count

    LOOP2
         DECFSZ   count,F  

    bra  LOOP2

    nop

    return 

    end
```

I tried simulate it at Proteus software, having this configuration:

[image]

I can actually see leds getting ON and OFF but nothing like a second, no matter how I change `movlw   .255` at `DELAY` subroutine. I tried with different higher values and got same wierd behaviour.

What did I get wrong?

Counting the instructions cycles at subroutines with `movlw   .255` should be more than 1 second I think. But still simulation shows it faster. Adding two more leds makes it seem even faster.

Comment: Yeah! I just reck it on. I tried with 255 but I'm not realling getting a second ...

Comment: Yeah, sorry.. I translated the code, I'm editing it now.

Comment: As I know if I want to put decimals, compiler will know it's a base 10 number prefixing a dot

Comment: I don't know how many cycles the DECFSZ instruction takes, but if you're counting 255 ticks on a 4MHz clock your delay will be 63.75µs. Even if it took five cycles for the instruction you'd still never see a blink.

Comment: Well that's why I have a `nop` at last. That should be inducing the retard.

Comment: A single nop and a return will add a trivial number of cycles. Your loop contains only the DECFSZ and branch instructions; my previous point remains.

Comment: When you figure this out, look at using the timers. Delay loops will prove very limiting if you want to do more than blink LEDs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `decfsz` instruction implicitly works on a one-byte (8-bit) register. The largest value that such a register can hold is hex FF (decimal 255). When you attempt to initialize `count` to decimal 1000 (hex 3E8), you're really just setting that register to the low-order 8 bits of that value, or E8 (decimal 232).

To get around this limitation of the `decfsz` instruction, the usual technique is to create a "nest" of two loops, each using a separate variable. This would allow you to execute the inner loop body as many as 65535 times (hex 0xFFFF).

```
    ; control variable for inner loop
    i equ 0

    ; control variable for outer loop
    j equ 1

    ; initialize j with the MSBs of the loop count
    movlw .1000 >> 8
    movwf j
    ; initialize i with the LSBs of the loop count
    movlw .1000 & 0xFF
    movwf i

loop:

    ; body of loop here

    nop

    ; end of inner loop
    decfsz i
    bra loop

    ; end of outer loop
    decfsz j
    bra loop
```

Note that the inner loop runs the number of times `i` is initialized to on the first iteration of the outer loop. Every time after that, it runs 256 times.

Comment: Thanks, I checked it and it works nice. The problem is the time. I want delays to be 1 second

Comment: OK, with a 4 MHz CPU clock, you need to execute instructions that add up to 1,000,000 machine cycles. If the loop body is just a single `nop`, then each iteration will require 4 machine cycles, which means you'll need to execute 250,000 iterations. This is too many for the double-nested loop, so you can either put more instructions into the loop body, or you can add a third level of looping.

Comment: Or use a more appropriate delay mechanism, such as the timer module acting as a counter, with the input scaled from the oscillator.

Comment: @David can you offer an example?

Comment: @DaveTweed can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

http://www.piclist.com/cgi-bin/delay.exe

probably the most useful site ever created. (After this one!)

It should be noted that whilst this will solve your problem, it will also teach you absolutely nothing about how to go about programming your own, although if you read the code it generates  you can work it out.

The other answer should be read properly if you want a real understanding. This is just to get  stuff working.

Comment: Can you offer an example about how to use the generated code in own code?

Comment: Type in what you need, in terms of seconds or clock cycles, input your clock freq, give it a unique name (my1SecDelay), then hit the generate button. The site you are taken to provides the code for you, all you need to do is copy and paste it, but MAKE SURE you declare the variables at the top of your code, in ASM its something like: delay1 equ 0x28h. then you are done, just call it.

Comment: To use it you just use "call my1SecDelay" or what ever you have named it.

Comment: Sorry, edit: If you have declared the var's it needs, at the top you your code, then you don't need the start of it up to the point when it says ;4999 (or however many) cycles. I.E throw away the "cblock
 d1
 d2
 d3
 endc" 
Part